# Nullable string property/column in nHibernate + Fluent

Tags: c#, string, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm new to nHibernate universe, so this question can be idiot ..
I have a table with a nullable nvarchar column.
In the mapping i use this `Map(c => c.Genero, "genero").Nullable();`
In the property i use trim to set the value, so i have a private string and a public virtual string.
When i do an select in this table i receive an runtime error in the setter of this property.
I tryed to pass this property to Nullable, but i receive a compile-time error saying `The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'`.

How can i do this ?

Thanks for everyone !

UPDATE

If i use just the property with { get; set; } works normally, but i need to trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you can't trim a null string. Try:

```
public string Genero
{
    get { return _genero; }
    set { _genero = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : value.Trim(); }
}
```

Depending on your mapping, this may cause the trimmed string to be written to the database when the session is flushed. It might be better to map the string as a private field and trim it in the getter.